# How can I subtract 2 quaternions in threejs

Tags: three.js

I have an object called 'plus' in threejs. It is in the scene. I want to clone that 'plus' object with it's orientation and put it on to another object called 'mesh' in the scene.

But I want that cloned plus to be mesh's child. Even though this mesh has its own direction on the scene, I want that cloned and added plus object to have the same orientation with the plus just before cloned.

But when I clone and add that cloned plus on to the mesh, the cloned object's orientation changes. I guess cloned object's quaternion is applied on to the mesh's own local orientation. so when I add that it never look at the same direction with the plus in the scene.

Here is some of my code:

```
// here is the originalPlus. Assume I got it from previous code
originalPlus; 

// I create the plus object
var plus2Add = createPlus();

// I find the mesh where mouse ray intersects
const rayCasterx = new THREE.Raycaster()
mousePosition4DoubleClick.set(
    (event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1,
    -(event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1
)
rayCasterx.setFromCamera(mousePosition4DoubleClick,cameraPers);
const intersects = rayCasterx.intersectObjects(meshesss,false);
const mesh = intersects[0].object as THREE.Mesh

// I want plus2Add object to have same position with originalPlus
plus2Add.position.copy(mesh.worldToLocal(originalPlus.position))

// I want plus2Add object to have same orientation with originalPlus
..............

// here what I have done so far

var worldQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion()
originalPlus.getWorldQuaternion(worldQuaternion)
console.log("plus world quaternion", worldQuaternion)

var meshWorldQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion()
mesh.getWorldQuaternion(meshWorldQuaternion)
console.log("mesh world quaternion", meshWorldQuaternion)

var yLocalQuaternion = worldQuaternion.multiply(meshWorldQuaternion.conjugate());
plus2Add.setRotationFromQuaternion(yLocalQuaternion)
mesh.add(plus2Add)
```

But this doesnt give me the same orientation with originalPlus orientation when I add that on to the mesh
I am stuck. thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps `mesh.attach( object )` is what you are trying to do.